# Can HBase provide real time write / read access to its cell?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I heard from some sources that HBase is a "batch" process based on Hadoop so I am not sure if HBase can provide real time write / read access to its cell?

For example, for a piece of data that the application wants to write to a certain cell in the HBase table, will HBase need to go through the batch process used in Map-Reduce to put the data to the cell? If that's the case, then this application can't read this new piece of data from HBase until the batch process is finished...

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does provide 'real time' access.

The 'batch' process that you are referring to is MapReduce on Hadoop. HBase, relies only on HDFS for storage and has no dependency on mapreduce.

Comment: The only other question that I have is - then what's the mechanism that HBase uses to write/read data to its table (if the tables are stored in the networked clustered servers?) thanks!

Comment: The HDFS documentation [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/hdfs_user_guide.html) will give you a good overview. 

HBase uses the HDFS apis which abstract away (for the most part) the distributed storage related issues from it.

Comment: Thanks Ambar. It appears that using the APIs will take away some distributed storage issues from an application developer's point of view. However, if we dig into things behind these APIs, I am still not sure how data are transferred and stored in the data nodes. Can we assume that the API always communicate with the Master node and then write data to the data nodes immediately in Real time, not through batch processes?

Comment: 'real-time' is a bad term to use here.  I would prefer a term line 'online'.  HBase can be very fast, but it does not provide any guarantees about how quickly it will respond to a given request.

Comment: @David is right about the terminology here.

user1660652 , as I said, there is no batching like mapreduce. From the application developer's PoV, there are mainly get and put style operations which are synchronous and return as soon as they succeed (or fail).

Comment: Writes do not all go through the master node.  That would be a bottleneck.  Once a client knows the server it needs to communicate with, then it communicates directly to the region server.  Going through the master would be an unacceptable bottleneck.